# Website Theme Flickering in Chrome

Tags: themes

This website - https://www.millworksconstructionservices.com/ - flickers when you scroll down in Chrome. I get this issue at home and in the office, and unofortunately clients are starting to report the issue. If I switch over to another theme, the flickering goes away. Any idea on a fix for this?

Chrome: Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Nice site. For starters, it looks like you might have some issues with some missing files and some javascript errors. This could be competing with the smooth loading of your site. If you 'Inspect' your site (right-click and 'Inspect') you'll see a bunch of errors, and the errors multiply (for jquery.smoothscroll) as you scroll up and down.

I'd be looking at your 'Cherry Framework' and Cherry plugins/shortcodes, if I were you, as the first port of call. Try to deactivate plugins and see if that helps, otherwise you might need to tackle your theme.

[image: js errors]